# What actually changed in this proposed change?

Tags: discussion, documentation, documentation-editor

I came across this request: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/84755?draftId=71050

When you expand out the side-by-side markdown, all lines are identical.

What actually happened here? How was the user able to submit a request without anything actually changing? Or is this some weird NBSP edge case?

My main concern is with the lack of feedback to a reviewer. If there has been a change, then it should be indicated somewhere. If there was a change that has since been integrated by another request, then why is this still up for review?

<sub><sub>According to Quill: [I have no idea, pure black magic](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5183243#5183243)</sub></sub>

Comment: Probably a minor change that is included in someone else's approved change.

Comment: In that case it would be mighty helpful if that was indicated in any way to a potential reviewer. Also, if that's the case why is it up for review?

Comment: The only thing that changed was you.